Grunt tasks trying to create an existing directory and failing with code EEXIST
I've pulled down a codebase to a new machine with a newer version of Windows. Without changing anything in the gruntfile, which works on the old machine, I am getting the following error from my uglify task:
"Warning: Unable to create directory "Scripts/assets" (Error code: EEXIST). Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings."
I am getting the same error from my sass task:
"Fatal error: Unable to create directory "Content" (Error code: EEXIST)."
If I delete the folders, I no longer get the error, and the uglify task generates a new js file but the sass task does not generate a new css file. I can't delete the folder as an actual solution, in any case, because the folders contain other necessary files which are not regenerated.
Here are the package versions I'm using with Node 8.7.1:
    "grunt": "^1.6.1",
    "grunt-cdnify": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.0.0",

Here are the two tasks in my gruntfile:
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM tt") %> */\n',
                beautify: true, // false: minify code
                mangle: false // true: rename variables to one character letter

            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                        'Scripts/assets/application.js': 
                        [
                            'Scripts/lodash.js',
                            ...
                            'Scripts/ViewModels/*.js',
                        ]
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'Content/application.css': 'Content/scss/application.scss'
                },
                options: {
                    //Details: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
                    sourcemap: 'file',
                    outputStyle: 'compressed'
                }
            }
        },

I've tried reinstalling node (using windows nvm, after deleting node_modules) and grunt, I've tried running command prompt as administrator, and I've verified that the administrator account has full permissions for the files.
I'm having difficulty understanding why these grunt tasks are trying to create the folders. Can you suggest a solution?
Note that this question is similar to an existing, unanswered question:
grunt-contrib-copy stops with EEXIST error

Change grunt to use version 1.5.3 and it will work. I haven't found a solution to get it to work with 1.6+ (means use "grunt": "1.5.3" in your package.json)
